# database values not displaying in carousal in codeigniter php

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, carousel

i have a website in which i used carousel sliders to display images and its values, I have 3 carousel in my homepage, 3 of them have same code, however the first carousel is not displaying name and price like the 2nd and 3rd carousel:

[image]

as you can see in the image

the code for this carousel is below:

```html
<section class="carousel_sec">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row ">

      <h3 class="carousel_heading">Trending Birthday Cakes <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>kids_party-planner/cakes/MQ"><button class="pull-right"><span>VIEW ALL</span><!-- <span class="visible-xs">>></span> --></button></a></h3>

      <hr>



      <div class="carou">

        <div class="demo">

          <ul id="landing_products1">



            <?php foreach($trending_products1 as $key=>$val) { ?>

            <li>

              <div class="item">

                <div class="pad15 content_div">

                  <div class="carou_thumb">

                    <img class="st_img" src="<?php echo ADMIN_IMG.'cakes/'.$val['image'][0]['cake_image'];?>" alt="<?php echo $val['cake_name']; ?>" />

                    <a href="<?php echo base_url('event-details/cakes/1/'.$val['id'])?>"><img class="nd_img"  src="<?php echo ADMIN_IMG.'cakes/'.$val['image'][0]['cake_image'];?>"  alt="<?php echo $val['cake_name']; ?>" /></a>

                    <p>
                      <?php echo $val['cake_name']; ?>
                    </p>

                    <?php

                            $btp_price=0;$offer_price=0;

                                $btp_price=$val['price'][0]['btp_price'];

                                $offer_price=$val['price'][0]['offer_price'];

                             ?>

                      <div class="price text-center" style="width:100%;float:left;">



                        <span class="amount" style="color:#f2136e;font-size:14px;">

                                 <?php echo PRICE_UNIT;?><?php echo  $offer_price;?>

                              </span> (



                        <s>&nbsp;<?php echo $btp_price;?></s>)

                        <span>&nbsp;</span>

                        <br>

                      </div>

                      <!--<br><span><?php echo PRICE_UNIT;100; ?></span></p>-->


                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>

            </li>

            <?php } ?>

          </ul>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</section>

<?php } ?>
```

while inspecting in browser the value is showing, the live URL is [enter link description here](https://www.booktheparty.in/)
can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to tweak the css to reveal the content that is hidden.

To push you in the direction, see the improvement with:

```
#landing_products1 {
    height: 330px;
    margin-top: -65px;
}
```

I don't know how responsive you need to be with your UI, so let's call this a temporary fix.  The first carousel's dimensions don't perfectly match the others, so I'll leave the fine tuning to you.

It also appears that you have some js and css issues to mop up.

Comment: thank you, if you have time can u please check why is there too much flickering in my menu

Comment: I recommend before moving forward that you fix all of the js and css errors.  Then if you have trouble with flickering, ask a new question.